# SQL query serialization to json file in classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, json, asp-classic

I'm trying to serialize a SQL query in ASP to a json object like this:

[["name1","phone1","email1","address1"],["name2","phone2","email2","address2"]]

I've made two loops to go through the columns and the rows of the db and this is how i got so far;

```
<!--#include file="JSON_2.0.4.asp"-->


SQL = "SELECT name, phone, email, address FROM clients"
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Recordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Connection.Open "Provider=sqloledb;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=mydatabase;UID=;PWD=1234;"  
Recordset.Open SQL,Connection

rsArray = Recordset.getRows()       

ReDim arrObj(UBound(rsArray, 2) - 1)

Dim i, j

For i = 1 To UBound(rsArray, 2)

    ReDim arrProp(UBound(rsArray, 1))

    For j = 0 To UBound(rsArray, 1)
        arrProp(j) = rsArray(j, i)
    Next 

Next

Response.Write toJSON(arrProp)
```

What am i getting wrong here, I've tried to change every value possible.
The result gives me just the last row of the table(like the following) of course i would like to retrive every row from the table.
Thank you in advance for any possible answer.

["La Musical Fashion","214478457","musical@fashion.pt","Av. Quinta Grande, 8 R/C Esq."]

Comment: just curious - I don't see where you're setting any values in the JSON? As each part of the object needs to be serialized as n/v pair. Again, just a thought in looking at the code shown.

Comment: well I'm using "aspjson" http://code.google.com/p/aspjson/ you just name the object you want to serialize "Response.Write toJSON(arrProp)" and it puts it to a json string

Comment: first I user this code but i had to set the size of the array and I want it to automatically access the number off columns and rows.  

 Dim a(50,3)   

 For i = 0 to UBound(rsArray, 2)
 
  a(i,0) = (rsArray(0,i))
  a(i,1) = (rsArray(1,i))
  a(i,2) = (rsArray(2,i))
  a(i,3) = (rsArray(3,i))  
   
 Next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to build an `Array of Arrays` like `Array(Array(col1,col2,col3), Array(col1,col2,col3))` to get desired result obtained through `toJSON`.
You can do it with something like below.

```
rsArray = Recordset.getRows()

ReDim Rows(UBound(rsArray, 2))
ReDim Row(UBound(rsArray, 1))
For i = 0 To UBound(Rows)
    For j = 0 To UBound(Row)
        Row(j) = rsArray(j, i)
    Next 
    Rows(i) = Row
Next
Response.Write toJSON(Rows)
```

Comment: YES! this does it, thanks a lot Kul-Tigin, I´m kind of a newbie and this is my first venture in ASP and JavaScript and I really needed this kind of data formatting.
Cheers and thanks again.